# A Measure For The Space of Probability Density Functions

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the space of all joint probability density functions of two variables. I want to know what the measure is of the portion of this space that is filled by uncorrelated joint pdfs relative to the size of the entire space. In other words, what is the fraction of all possible joint pdfs that are uncorrelated?

The motivations for the question is a desire to quantify how much it matters if I take into account correlations or not, for a generic joint pdf.

Any ideas for directions to look would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're attacking this from the wrong angle.

First, your idea is fraught with technical difficulties. You didn't mention what *kind* of space you envision this space of PDFs to be. You could start with just the set, and simply define a $\sigma$-algebra on its powerset. But there's a myriad of ways to do that, which one do you pick?

Or you could find a topology, and try to create the analog of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on your set. That means picking a topology first. Now, if you look at all *distributions* (CDFs), I think the Lévy-metric might give you a topology which corresponds to convergence in measure. For PDFs, however, things are harder, because not all distributions have PDFs.

Say you *have* picked a suitable topology, and used that to define a $\sigma$-algebra. How are you going to define a measure? Doing this involves some kind of idea about which sets are supposed to have large measures, and which sets small ones. In other words, you need to have an idea about which PDFs are likely, and which are unlikely. Even picking a kind of "uniform" measure won't solve this - it'll then be the metric (or topology) you picked which actually defines this.

I think you have to *start* with asking yourself *which* PDFs you want to consider. It seems that what you're actually interested in is estimating (for a specific situation?) how "likely" it is for two random variables to be correlated. For that question to be meaningful, however, you have to define the circumstances in *much* more detail than you have done here.

Comment: @fgp: I think you're right, I'll need to do some more thinking about how better to frame the question.